# "thank you" in an e-mail with additional doc

Tags: interviewing, email, email-etiquette

HR asked me to send an additional doc before the second meeting with a technical team.

Should I write something like:

"I am looking forward to my next interview"

Would you suggest adding something like this? Or would you write just: "Please find attached requested form"

Comment: Nothing wrong in adding a personal note.

Comment: Stop second guessing yourself. If you don't know what to do, just flip a coin.

Answer (score 10):

Reverse the order. You can write

> *<Required greetings!>*
>
> Please find attached a copy of the document which was requested.
>
> Please let me know if this meets the requirement, and when we can have the next round of discussion. Thanks.
>
> *<Your signature!>*

Comment: It's much better to be polite and enthusiastic and offer to help any way you can, rather than being aggressive and demanding "I want an interview". (I can't tell if this is the OP's intention or if they just come over like that due to bad English.)

Comment: @StuartF I believe it is a language barrier. I suggested an edit under the assumption that the OP meant to write "I am looking _forward to_ my next interview" rather than "I am looking _for_ my next interview". In either case, this is the right approach. There's never anything wrong with being pleasant! :)